# Disable Generation of Test Packages in Netbeans 8.1

Tags: netbeans

Every time I compile and run a new project for the first time in Netbeans 8.1 it generates test packages. I have to delete them by opening project properties and deleting the test packages under "Sources". But I would like to know how to disable test packages like these from being automatically generated.

[image: IMAGE: Generated Test Packages.]